# SyntaError pyspark using window and row_number

Tags: python, pyspark, syntax, syntax-error, filtering

Can someone help what could be the problem with the following codesnipets?
I get a syntaxerror and cannot figure it out.
I want to remove duplicates and keeping the first row in descending order of a spark df.
I use these:

```
window = Window.partitionBy(["RECEIPT_DT","nummer","CODE"]).orderBy("Year")

df.withColumn('row', f.row_number().over(window.desc()).filter(f.col('row') == 1).drop('row')
```

or

```
(df
    .withColumn('row', f.row_number().over( Window.partitionBy(["RECEIPT_DT","nummer","CODE"]).orderBy("Year").desc() ) \
    .filter(f.col('row') == 1)
    .drop("row"))
```

I always get **SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing**
at the end of the code?

Can u spot the problem pls? I do not understand why.
I'm working in databricks and imported:

```
from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
```

I have tried removing the drop or filter rows from the code, but still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a closing `)` after the over clause.
Also note you can't use Window.desc(), you have to put the desc in the orderBy clause.

The following snippet should work:

```
window = Window.partitionBy(["RECEIPT_DT","nummer","CODE"]).orderBy(f.col("Year").desc())
df.withColumn('row', f.row_number().over(window)).filter(f.col('row') == 1).drop('row')
```